# Why default FCN infer.py script only output a 1-channel Mat, How to get a RGB output?

Tags: neural-network, rgb, deep-learning, caffe, image-segmentation

I download and run the default `infer.py` script of FCN from [github](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org).

The output of `"score"` layer is just 1-channel Mat and can not be converted to RGB img, I know the raw output blob of score layer is `[1, 21, W, H]`, but how can I get a 3-channel RGB output instead of 1-channel img?
I have tried change the input data layer from `[1,3,W,H]` to `[3,3,W,H]` and use `PIL.Image.convert('RGB')`, however, Both failed.

I am a start learner in Image Segmentation, any suggestion is helpful and thanks a lot~

Source code in `infer.py`, which `out.shape = [W, H]`  (namely 1-channel not 3):

```
out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)
```

Comment: 1-channel output is correct, Why do you want/need RGB output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you get is indeed one number per pixel (2D and not 3D). The number you get is the class number (0 = "background", 1 = "aeroplane" etc.). In order to convert the *indexed output image* you have to RGB, you need to map (manually) each class label to a color. You should have a map from index 0..20 -> (R,G,B).

See [`voc_helper.py`](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc_helper.py) for a class implementing this conversion.

Comment: I get your point, really thank you for helping. The reason why I wonder this is that one of my friends who had run the fcn forward script several months ago told me that the output of him is RGB format, which is different from what I get recently.So I am puzzled after hearing this. Anyway, thanks a lot~

Comment: @YanhaoGE applying the map - the result is RGB, this is a deterministic stage. So in a sense you can say the output is RGB.

Answer (score 0):

FCN is trained to perform segmentation. So in the last layer, at each pixel of the 21 outputs it picks the one with the maximum value and uses that index to label the pixel. So we get a 1-channel segmentation output.

It is not possible to get an RGB image unless you train the network from the start to output RGB images (which is not segmentation).

Comment: The current input Imgs sent to conv_1 are RGB already, according to @Shai's answer, if I want to visualize the output in RGB then I need a map to map each class to a specific color. So the point is that I can't directly get a RGB output from any output blobs right ?

Comment: No. I don't think you can.

Comment: Thank you for help!